# Credit card interest calculator with grace period & different interest rate calculation methods?

Tags: credit-card, online-tools, interest, calculation

Is there an (ideally online) credit card interest calculator that 
includes grace periods and lets you choose the interest calculation 
method (eg, "adjusted balance", "average daily balance", "two-cycle 
average daily balance", and the other methods listed at 
http://credit.about.com/od/creditcardbasics/tp/finance-charge-calculation.htm)?

Most online interest calculators are much simpler and don't compensate 
for the complexities of grace periods and interest calculation 
methods.

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted this, but I've restored balance to the Force. +1.

Comment: Say there exists such a calculator.  What are you looking to do with this?  What insights are you looking for?

Comment: I want to know how much interest I'll pay in various scenarios, and what changes I can make to avoid paying interest at all.

Comment: Barry - it's simple - pay the balance in full every month. This will avoid all interest charges.

Comment: OK, but 1) what if I don't pay the full balance in July-- what's the situation for August?, and 2) I want to use the grace period to my advantage, and paying the whole balance monthly isn't always the best deal. Your answer is correct, but not complete.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6598 is helpful here to others seeking this answer.

Comment: I was surprised to find out today that I just got charged interest on my last credit card bill. I paid the credit card off, but I paid it off a little early. I think I did the same thing last month. So I guess I had a remaining balance since I paid it off early. Oops, didn't see that one coming. I tried to calculate how they arrived at the interest charge and couldn't. So this might be useful for me.

Comment: The only way to avoid an interest charge is to "touch zero" at least once prior to the due date. So there is no need for a complex calculator to figure out how to maximize your time without paying interest.

Comment: @Frazell It would still be nice to know the amount of interest you'd pay in various scenarios. If you can't touch zero pre the due date, you may still want to minimize interest.

Comment: Your interest costs are fixed (in the short term). The bank will generally calculate your interest charge using a formula similar to: (Interest Rate/365)*Days*Average Daily Balance. Interest is capitalized daily when not paid off in the grace period. So your only cheapest option is to pay as much as possible to keep the average daily balance as low as possible if you can't pay it all off.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was such a useful suggestion that I went ahead and created them. I'm sure you're not the only one who could derive some benefit from them, I know I will.

http://www.investy.com/tools

When I have some additional time, I will add the option for grace-periods, but for now I wanted to get them up so you could use the calculations as-is from the article.

Enjoy.

(Disclosure: I'm the founder of the site they are hosted on and I wrote the code for the calculators)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you stop paying interest, the best thing to do is to not use the card for a full billing cycle.

Calculating credit card interest with precision ahead of time is difficult, as how you use the card both in terms of how much and when is critical.

Comment: But, what if I'm looking to *reduce* or minimize my interest payments in situations where I can't or haven't not-used the card for a full billing cycle?